# NextJs Build Start Production is unable to receive data ReadableStream .getReader()

Tags: next.js, server-sent-events

I have a piece of code that works perfectly with `npm run dev` but when I run `npm run build` and then `npm run start` I dont receive the chunk of data. I am working on streaming data from OpenAI chat complete.
I logged the response from the server, and seems like server is sending the data but the front-end unable to read it. Could someone please help?

Here is a server side code.

```js
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

import { getChatHistory } from "./lib/createChatHist";
import { WritableStream } from "web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill";
import { getOpenAIStream } from "./lib/openAIStream";

export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {
    const body = req.body;
    const dataForAI = body["dataForAI"];
    const md = dataForAI["metaData"];

    const { payload} = getChatHistory(dataForAI);


    // console.log("payload", payload);

    const stream: ReadableStream = await getOpenAIStream(payload);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    res.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    const writableStream = new WritableStream({
        write(chunk) {
            console.log("sending chunk", chunk);
            res.write(chunk);
        },
        close() {
            console.log("closing the writable stream");
            res.end();
        },
        abort() {
            console.log("aborting");
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end();
        },
    });

    return stream.pipeTo(writableStream);
}
```

Here is the client side code

```js
export const getStreamData = async (
    dataForAI: any,
    URL: string,
    tmpChat: any,
    setCurrAIResp: any
) => {
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ dataForAI: dataForAI }),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    // This data is a ReadableStream
    const data = response.body;
    if (!data) {
        console.log("no data found int he body");

        return { usage: null, tCopy: tmpChat };
    }

    const reader = data.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let done = false;    
    let newAIResp = "";
    while (!done) {
    
        const { value, done: doneReading } = await reader.read();
        done = doneReading;
        const chunkValue = decoder.decode(value);

        console.log(doneReading, chunkValue, value);

        
            newAIResp += chunkValue;
            // console.log("newAIResp", newAIResp);
            setCurrAIResp({ role: "assitant", content: newAIResp });               
    }
};
```

here is the log from the server side. Which to me, it seems, that API is sending the data but my fronend is unable to read/receive it. The most baffling part is that the exact same code works flawlessly in dev environment. Something is happening during `npm run build`

```
14 dChunk data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7DgaIvMn0DlBUwy3Shk7Zg7IN7GLD","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1683496314,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":" you"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
sending chunk Uint8Array(4) [ 32, 121, 111, 117 ]
elta":{"content":" today"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
sending chunk Uint8Array(6) [ 32, 116, 111, 100, 97, 121 ]
18 dChunk data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7DgaIvMn0DlBUwy3Shk7Zg7IN7GLD","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1683496314,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"?"},"index":0,"finish_reason":null}]}
sending chunk Uint8Array(1) [ 63 ]
20 dChunk data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7DgaIvMn0DlBUwy3Shk7Zg7IN7GLD","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1683496314,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{},"index":0,"finish_reason":"stop"}]}
sending chunk Uint8Array(0) []
sending chunk Uint8Array(14) [
  84, 79, 75, 69, 78, 83,
  35, 35, 35, 52, 35, 35,
  35, 57
]
closing the writable stream
```

and lastly, this is the log from the front end. which means, all the data is received in shot instead of chunks. however the server side log says its sending chunks.

```
false 'Hello! How may I assist you today?TOKENS###4###9' Uint8Array(48) [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33, 32, 72, 111, 119, 32, 109, 97, 121, 32, 73, 32, 97, 115, 115, 105, 115, 116, 32, 121, 111, 117, 32, 116, 111, 100, 97, 121, 63, 84, 79, 75, 69, 78, 83, 35, 35, 35, 52, 35, 35, 35, 57, buffer: ArrayBuffer(48), byteLength: 48, byteOffset: 0, length: 48, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']

true '' undefined
```